# Map Keys sorting based on numbers and character

Tags: java, collections

```
[result][1]    
package info.sreenu.collectionsmap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class MapDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Map m=new HashMap();
m.put(1,"satya");
m.put('a',"anil");
m.put('b',"raju");
m.put('c',"nayana");
m.put(2,"hiyathi");
System.out.println(m.keySet());
System.out.println(m.values());
}
}
```

Here I need to sort the map keys based on numbers and based on characters.

Comment: Please can you describe the desired order for the keys in your example?

Comment: Ok, I suggest you write some code to try that.  Note: HashMap is not a sorted collection, but you can use a TreeMap which is. You will need to provide a custom comparator.

Comment: 12abc keys order@Paul

Comment: if i use TreeMap it Showin java.lang.ClassCastException @Peter

Comment: That's because Integer and Character are not mutually comparable by default. You need to write your own comparator for this, but mixing two types of keys is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Vijay try to use: m.put('1', ...

Comment: [1, a, b, 2, c]
[satya, anil, raju, hiyathi, nayana]

Comment: This is why I said, "You will need to provide a custom comparator. " as the default comparator will be unable to compare a number with a character.

Comment: Why is `2` between `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to use TreeMap instead of HashMap. That's sorts the data based on key.

[Here's](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashmap-vs-treemap-vs-hashtable-vs-linkedhashmap/) a better explanation of the same.

Secondly, you cannot insert both Integer and Character as a key because they cannot be casted. 
You can either write a **comparator** or convert all keys (Integer,Characters) to **String** and insert that as Key.

```
Map m=new TreeMap();
m.put(String.valueOf(1),"satya");
m.put(String.valueOf('a'),"anil");
m.put(String.valueOf('b'),"raju");
m.put(String.valueOf('c'),"nayana");
m.put(String.valueOf(2),"hiyathi");
System.out.println(m.keySet());
System.out.println(m.values());
```

Refer to [this](http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/treemap/comparator-user-object/) on how to use comparators with TreeMap.

Comment: This is i expected result. Thank you @Kishore

Comment: [1, 2, a, b, c]
[satya, hiyathi, anil, raju, nayana]

Comment: @Vijay Welcome, Can you accept the answer and close out the question?